# What's the meaning of the daily memory-time quota in the context of Azure Function Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-app-service-envrmnt, faas

Within an Azure Function App it is possible to define a [daily memory-time quota](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.site.dailymemorytimequota?view=azure-dotnet).

Unfortunately I was not able to find an official resource from Microsoft stating what setting this value actually means.

What is a memory-time quota? What does it mean if I set the value e.g. to 1000?

Answer (score 4):

Here is [document](https://markheath.net/post/deploying-azure-functions-with-azure-cli)(refer to `Step 7 - Configure a Daily Use Quota` for the details.) about `daily memory-time quota`.

In short, when using `Azure Functions consumption plan`, it offers near-infinite scale to handle huge spikes in load. But that does also leave you open to a "denial of wallet attack" where due to an external DoS attack or a coding mistake, you end up with a huge bill because your function app scaled out to hundreds of instances. The daily quota allows you to set a limit in terms of "Gigabyte seconds" (GB-s).

For "Gigabyte seconds", you can refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611198/10185816).

Hope it helps.